# DataSource.Connection Invalid Class

Tags: apex

I am writing a custom Lightning Connect connector. However, none of the classes in new DataSource namespace are available, I get the error 'Invalid class'. I have tried the code in a sandbox environment running summer 15 code, the same error exists in summer 15 sandbox also.

Comment: Can it be because additional apex lightening connect license is required?

Comment: I've asked support to understand why

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the exact same issue.